# Electrical engineering Software developed

Tags: patentability

I have developed a computer program for power system FACTS And load modelling to analyse the performance of electrical power system. How can i patent it india.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as you patent anything anywhere: by preparing and filing a patent application. This should of course only be done if your invention is novel and non-obvious, and is not otherwise excluded from patentability. Since you obviously cannot provide the full details of your invention to us (since that would be a public disclosure) we cannot comment further on your particular invention.

To this end, a patent attorney would certainly be the first port of call for you to proceed.